# how do I convert this Ajax.Request call (in prototype) to a $.ajax call (in jquery)?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I have an Ajax call written in prototype and need to convert it to jquery.  I'm not well versed in requestHeaders and the like, so I'm a bit stumped.  Here's the prototype version:

```
function poll_for_update(feed_id, last_modified, link) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    new Ajax.Request('/feeds/' + feed_id, {
      method: 'get',
      requestHeaders: { 'If-Modified-Since': last_modified },
      onComplete: function(transport) {
        if (transport.status == 304) {
          poll_for_update(feed_id, last_modified, link);
        } else if (transport.status == 200) {
          $('feed_' + feed_id).innerHTML = transport.responseText
        } else {
          link.innerHTML = 'error'
        }
      }
    }) },
    1000
  )
}
```

Since I can extract the feed_id and last_modified dates from the link, my early version of the corresponding jquery functions looks like this:

```
function poll_for_update(link) {
    var feed_id = $(link).attr('feed_id')
    var last_modified = $(link).attr('last_modified')
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: show_path(link),
            type: 'get',
            ifModified: true,
            headers: { 'If-Modified-Since': last_modified },
            statusCode: {
                404: function() {
                    alert('404');
                },
                304: function() {
                    alert('304');
                },
                200: function() {
                    alert('200');
                }
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                alert('success');
            },
            complete: function() {
                alert('complete');
            }});
    }, 1000)
}
```

A few things I can't figure out:

- how do I extract `transport.status` from within the complete() function?
- do I need the statusCode: clause, or is the complete: clause sufficient?
- is the ifModified clause necessary?

... etc.

(For the curious, this is a transcription of Adam Wiggins's tutorial on [how to build a queue-backed feed reader](http://adam.heroku.com/past/2009/4/14/building_a_queuebacked_feed_reader_part_2/), which is super useful but somewhat outdated.)

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with, and it appears to work.  What wasn't obvious to me was that the 'transport' object is passed as an argument to the completion() method.  Once I realized that, the jquery implementation is quite close to the prototype version:

```
function poll_for_update(link) {
    var feed_id = $(link).attr('feed_id')
    var last_modified = $(link).attr('last_modified')
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: show_path(link),
            type: 'get',
            headers: { 'If-Modified-Since': last_modified },
            complete: function( transport ) {
                if (transport.status == 304) {
                    poll_for_update(link)
                } else if (transport.status == 200) {
                    $('#feed_' + feed_id).html(transport.responseText)
                } else {
                    $(link).html('error ' + transport.status)
                }
            }
        });
    }, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can get the transport.status from the jqXHR object, as discussed here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR
2. If you use the jqXHR object passed in as the first parameter to complete, you should be able to handle all kinds of "completions" in there
3. ifModified is explained as "Allow the request to be successful only if the response has changed since the last request."  If this is what you would like, then use this flag.  It would be useful if you were trying to prevent people from submitting the same data twice or something like this.